# Adding a JSON file into my table using a button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have been import JSON in my JS file, and i want to display it using a button in my table but, the JSON file its a list of users, and i want to add one user on each click.
I've been trying so many codes with no success, i got to see that something happend in my console.log() but i never got to see it on the web.
i hope the question its clear to understand..

Does anybody have an idea??

my code:

imports + JSON

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import InitialData from '../../JSON/InitialData';
import AdditionalData from '../../JSON/AdditionalData';

const { supportRequest } = InitialData;
const { users } = AdditionalData;


class SupportRequest extends Component {

  state = {

    text: "Send",
 
    users: [
      {
        name: "Bob Sacamento",
        email: "bob_sacamento@gottlieb.ca",
        timestamp: "2012-04-23T11:06:43.511Z",
        phoneNumber: "214-300-5846",
        city: "Long Island",
        status: "unsent"
      },
      {
        name: "Hal Kitzmiller",
        email: "hal_kitzmiller@lindgren.com",
        timestamp: "2012-04-23T08:22:43.511Z",
        phoneNumber: "057-812-4000",
        city: "The Bronx",
        status: "unsent"
      },
      {
        name: "Bob Cobb",
        email: "bob.cobb@nelson.tv",
        timestamp: "2012-04-23T14:22:43.511Z",
        phoneNumber: "866-668-0327",
        city: "Florence",
        status: "unsent"
      },
      {
        name: "Mike Moffett",
        email: "mike_moffett@kaia.org",
        timestamp: "2012-04-23T07:22:43.511Z",
        phoneNumber: "647-851-1333",
        city: "Upper East Side",
        status: "unsent"
      }
    ]
  }
```

the Add button:

```
addUser = () => {
  const array = this.state.users;
  array.map((arr) => {
    return (users.push({ users: arr[0] })
    )
  })
}


render() {

  return (
    <div>
      <div style={{ fontSize: "25px" }} className="jsonData-container">Support Request</div>
      <button
        style={{ variant: "contained", alignContent: "flex-end" }}
        onClick={() => this.addUser
        }
      >
        Add
          </button>
```

Rest of the code:

```
      <div className="container" ></div>
      <table className="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
        <thead style={{ backgroundColor: "black", color: "white" }}>
          <tr>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>email</th>
            <th>timestamp</th>
            <th>phoneNumber</th>
            <th>city</th>
            <th>status</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {supportRequest.map((supportRequest, index) => {
            return (
              <tr key={index}>
                <td >
                  {supportRequest.name}
                </td>
                <td>
                  {supportRequest.email}
                </td>
                <td>
                  {supportRequest.timestamp}
                </td>
                <td>
                  {supportRequest.phoneNumber}
                </td>
                <td>
                  {supportRequest.city}
                </td>
                <td>
                  <button
                    onClick={() => {
                      this.setState({ text: 'send' })

                      console.log(this.setState({}))
                    }}>
                    {supportRequest.status}
                  </button>
                </td>
              </tr>
            )
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  )
}
}

export default SupportRequest;
```

Comment: `array.map((arr) => {
    return (users.push({ users: arr[0] })
    )
  })` does nothing visibly but why a map? It is the same as `array.forEach(arr =>  users.push({ users: arr[0] }))`

Comment: I've tried to map between the users, so i could ADD each user individual by clicking the ADD button to the table.
Is there another way that you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `React.Children` from `React` [React.Children](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildrentoarray). As you have already retrieved the user data, you don't have to create new list of users on each `click`. You can simply control the view.

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    text: "Send",

    users: [
      {
        name: "Bob Sacamento",
        email: "bob_sacamento@gottlieb.ca",
        timestamp: "2012-04-23T11:06:43.511Z",
        phoneNumber: "214-300-5846",
        city: "Long Island",
        status: "unsent",
      },
      {
        name: "Hal Kitzmiller",
        email: "hal_kitzmiller@lindgren.com",
        timestamp: "2012-04-23T08:22:43.511Z",
        phoneNumber: "057-812-4000",
        city: "The Bronx",
        status: "unsent",
      },
      {
        name: "Bob Cobb",
        email: "bob.cobb@nelson.tv",
        timestamp: "2012-04-23T14:22:43.511Z",
        phoneNumber: "866-668-0327",
        city: "Florence",
        status: "unsent",
      },
      {
        name: "Mike Moffett",
        email: "mike_moffett@kaia.org",
        timestamp: "2012-04-23T07:22:43.511Z",
        phoneNumber: "647-851-1333",
        city: "Upper East Side",
        status: "unsent",
      },
    ],
    usersToShow: 3,
  };

  onLoadMore = () => {
    this.setState({
      usersToShow: this.state.usersToShow + 1,
    });
  };

  onViewLess = () => {
    this.setState({
      usersToShow: this.state.usersToShow - 1,
    });
  };

  showUerData = () =>
    this.state.users.map((user, i) => <p key={i}>{user.name}</p>);

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {React.Children.toArray(this.showUerData()).slice(
          0,
          this.state.usersToShow
        )}

        {this.state.usersToShow === this.state.users.length ? (
          <button onClick={this.onViewLess}>View Less</button>
        ) : (
          <button onClick={this.onLoadMore}>Load More</button>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: hey, thanks for the quick answer :)
I've tried this but it wont get the result..
Instead of show to users inside the table, it show the users outside the table.
I will try different way.. I'll play with it a bit :)